# Macadamia nuts in Malaysian cooking

Tags: nuts

I've seen that macadamia nuts can be used as a substitute for candlenuts in Malaysian cooking. Is it a 1:1 substitution or do you need more macadamias. I'm not familiar with candlenuts, but pictures suggest they are larger than macadamias.

Comment: Are you counting the nuts? That's the only way the size really matters unless a single nut is large enough to account for a fair proportion of the total. Weight for weight 1:1 should be good. Volume for volume 1:1 would be a good start but you may want to adjust to suit you in the future.

Comment: @ChrisH: Promote the comment to an answer, it's entirely correct :)

Answer (score 4):

The only way the size really matters is if you're counting the nuts - unless a single nut is large enough to account for a fair proportion of the total. Weight for weight 1:1 should be good. Volume for volume 1:1 would be a good start but you may want to adjust to suit you in the future.

If you were using larger nuts than the recipe called for, halving then (or chopping them) might be a good idea.